# Add support for AWS IAM token connection to Redis

Tags: redis, quarkus, vert.x, mutiny, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Im trying to connect to an AWS ElasticCache Redis server but I always got this error :

```json
{
            "name": "Redis connection health check",
            "status": "DOWN",
            "data": {
                "reason": "client [<default>]: timeout"
            }
        },
```

This is because I need to generate a token prior to make a connection attempt.
I try to use the [low lever driver](https://quarkus.io/guides/redis-reference#apis) as explained here. But I can't find how to pass any AwsCredentialsProvider.

This [sample code](https://github.com/aws-samples/elasticache-iam-auth-demo-app/blob/main/src/main/java/com/amazon/elasticache/IAMAuthDemoApp.java) from AWS uses the Lettuce driver.

Here is some [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html).

I have to use it with the [STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.html)

Here is some [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-assume-role-credentials.html)

How to make it work ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For such a use case, you need to provide a CDI bean implementing `RedisHostsProvider`:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@Identifier("my-host-provider") // the name of the host provider
public class ExampleRedisHostProvider implements RedisHostsProvider {
    @Override
    public Set<URI> getHosts() {
        // Compute your token
        var host = ...
        // Create the URI
        return Collections.singleton(URI.create(host));
    }
}
```

It's a CDI bean, so it can create the application configuration (@ConfigProperty) or use other beans (using plain `@Inject`).

Then, you need to configure the Redis client to use your host provider:

```
quarkus.redis.hosts-provider-name=my-host-provider
```

*References*:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/redis-reference#programmatic-redis-hosts
- https://quarkus.io/guides/redis-reference#customize-the-redis-options-programmatically